# Android MVVM - Should fragments contain if statements?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-mvvm

I've been trying to learn MVVM and I have a question regarding the kind of logic that is acceptable for a fragment to contain in order to follow the pattern.

For example when showing a loader, should it be separated into two different states, or is it acceptable to have one state with a boolean argument and for the fragment to handle that logic?

So in the view model should the code be like this

```
fun makeCall() {
    _state.value = Loading(true)
    // make the call
    _state.value = Loading(false)
}
```

and in the fragment have the check

```
private fun handleLoadingState(loading: Boolean) {
    if (loading) {
        binding.loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        binding.loader.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

or like this?

```
fun makeCall() {
    _state.value = ShowLoader
    // make the call
    _state.value = HideLoader
}
```

and this

```
private fun handleShowLoaderState() {
    binding.loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

private fun handleHideLoaderState() {
    binding.loader.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

If both ways are correct is maybe one of them considered better? Or it doesn't really matter which one I use?

Comment: You can make a Boolean variable in your viewModel after that you can add an XML tag of loader and switch it's visibility by that viewmodel variable. You will just have to change variable value and it will switch the visibility. If you want code then I will share

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean with data binding? I'm only using view binding. The code could be helpful